# wine unmet dependencies:

Tags: apt, dependencies, wine, aptitude

I believe that at one point i uninstalled wine however when i try to install wine again i get this:

```
~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 4.0~bionic)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

my sources file:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Ubuntu version:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I've tried aptitude & sudo apt install -f

Comment: Related: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+"you+have+held+broken+packages"+wine